# How to cover email template in Test class

Tags: unit-test

How to cover below Line of code in Test class:

```
  @AuraEnabled
public static string getEmailTemplateFolder1(String folderId,String templateName,List<Case> clist,String templateId)
{
    Map<Id,Case> cMap = new Map<Id,Case>();
    String errormsg = '';
    Messaging.Email[] allMails = new List <Messaging.Email>();
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mailList = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    system.debug('clist    '+clist);
    system.debug('templateId    '+templateId);
    system.debug('folderId    '+folderId);
    system.debug('templateName    '+templateName);


    if(clist!=NULL && !clist.isEmpty())
    {

        if(folderId!=NULL && folderId !='')
        {
            if(templateId!=NULL && templateId!='' && templateName!=NULL && templateName!='')
            {
                for(Case crec : clist)
                {
                    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();         
                    mail.setTemplateId(templateId);
                    system.debug('crec.ContactEmail    '+crec.ContactEmail);
                    system.debug('crec.ContactId   '+crec.ContactId);
                   if(crec.ContactEmail!=NULL && crec.ContactEmail!='')
                   {
                        mail.setTargetObjectId(crec.ContactId);
                        mail.setWhatId(crec.Id);
                        mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);  
                        mailList.add(mail);
                        system.debug('Mailme    '+mail);
                        cMap.put(crec.Id,crec);

                   }
                }

            }
            else
                errormsg='Please select Email Template';
        }
        else
            errormsg='Please select Folder';                        
    }
    system.debug('errormsg114    '+errormsg);
    for(Integer j = 0; j < mailList.size(); j++ ){
        allMails.add(mailList.get(j));
    }
    system.debug('allMails118 '+allMails);
    if(allMails!=NULL && !allMails.isEmpty())   //check if allmails list is not empty
    { 
        try 
        {
            GSS_UtilityClass.isTaskTriggerCheck = true;//5th-Feb-2016   Smita (CR-00036669):Initializing to bypass task triggers
            Messaging.sendEmail(allMails);    //sending the complete list of mails
            // System.debug('allMails *****'+allMails[0]);
            GSSCaseController gssCase = new GSSCaseController();
            gssCase.insertTasks(mailList,cMap);
            gssCase.updateCaseLastTouchTime(clist);
            system.debug('Success130');
            //PageReference pref = new PageReference('/500/o');
            // return pref;
            errormsg='Success';
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
            errormsg='We have encountered some errors while sending mails. Please contact your System Administrator.';
            System.debug('ex**'+ex.getMessage()+ex.getLineNumber());
            CreateGSSApexErrorLog.insertGSSErrorLogs(ex, null, null, null, 'ApexClass', 'Case',null,'GSS_NotifyCustomerController', 'sendemail');

        }
    }
    return errormsg;

}
```

Test class :

```
    @isTest
  public class GSSCaseController_Test {
  public static testmethod void  testGetAllcases(){
    List<case> caseList=new List<case>();
    map<id,case>casemap=new map<id,case>();
    List<string>caseIds=new List<string>();
    GSS_TestDataFactory.setupdata();

    Id endCustomerAccRecId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('End Customer').getRecordTypeId();
    Id custContactRecId = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Customer Contact').getRecordTypeId();

    account   account=new account(name='testing time',recordtypeId=endCustomerAccRecId,Country__c='albania',type='territory');        
    insert account;
    // Insert Contact
    contact  newContact=new contact(LastName='testing user',email='testing@testing.com',recordtypeId=custContactRecId,accountid=account.id);        
    insert  newContact;         

    for(integer i=0;i<=2;i++){
        Case C=new Case();
        C.Status='Pending';
        c.accountId=account.Id;
        c.contactId=newContact.Id;
        C.Type='Incident';
        C.Priority='4-Low';
        C.Description='qwertty'+i;
        C.Subject='xyz';
        c.Sub_Status__c='Waiting on Customer';
        caseList.add(c);
    }
    insert caseList;

    for(case c:caseList){
        caseIds.add(c.Id);
        casemap.put(c.Id,c);
    }
    EmailTemplate validEmailTemplate;
    System.runAs (new User(Id = UserInfo.getUserId()) ){
        validEmailTemplate = new EmailTemplate();
        validEmailTemplate.isActive = true;
        validEmailTemplate.Name = 'name';
        validEmailTemplate.DeveloperName = 'unique_name_addSomethingSpecialHere';
        validEmailTemplate.TemplateType = 'text';
        validEmailTemplate.FolderId = UserInfo.getUserId();

        insert validEmailTemplate;
    }
    GSSCaseController.getEmailTemplateFolder1(validEmailTemplate.FolderId,validEmailTemplate.Name,caseList,validEmailTemplate.Id);
}
```

}

below line of code isnot covering in test class:

```
      if(crec.ContactEmail!=NULL && crec.ContactEmail!='')
                   {
                        mail.setTargetObjectId(crec.ContactId);
                        mail.setWhatId(crec.Id);
                        mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);  
                        mailList.add(mail);
                        system.debug('Mailme    '+mail);
                        cMap.put(crec.Id,crec);

                   }
```

**Based on @crmprogdev suggestion**

Test class:

```
  public static testmethod void testCaseList(){
      List<case> caseList=new List<case>();
    map<id,case>casemap=new map<id,case>();
    List<string>caseIds=new List<string>();
    GSS_TestDataFactory.setupdata();

    Id endCustomerAccRecId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('End Customer').getRecordTypeId();
    Id custContactRecId = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Customer Contact').getRecordTypeId();

    account   account=new account(name='testing time',recordtypeId=endCustomerAccRecId,Country__c='albania',type='territory');        
    insert account;
    // Insert Contact
    contact  newContact=new contact(LastName='testing user',email='testing@testing.com',recordtypeId=custContactRecId,accountid=account.id);        
    insert  newContact;         

    for(integer i=0;i<=2;i++){
        Case C=new Case();
        C.Status='Pending';

        c.contactId=newContact.Id;
        C.Type='Incident';
        C.Priority='4-Low';
        C.Description='qwertty'+i;
        C.Subject='xyz';
        c.Sub_Status__c='Waiting on Customer';
        caseList.add(c);
    }
    insert caseList;

    for(case c:caseList){
        system.debug('--->'+c.ContactEmail);  //value is null
    }

    for(case c:caseList){
        caseIds.add(c.Id);
        casemap.put(c.Id,c);
    }
     EmailTemplate validEmailTemplate;
    System.runAs (new User(Id = UserInfo.getUserId()) ){
        validEmailTemplate = new EmailTemplate();
        validEmailTemplate.isActive = true;
        validEmailTemplate.Name = 'name';
        validEmailTemplate.DeveloperName = 'unique_name_addSomethingSpecialHere';
        validEmailTemplate.TemplateType = 'text';
        validEmailTemplate.FolderId = UserInfo.getUserId();

        insert validEmailTemplate;
    }
    GSSCaseController.getEmailTemplateFolder1(validEmailTemplate.FolderId,validEmailTemplate.Name,null,validEmailTemplate.Id);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your unit test needs to have separate methods for each of the conditions you are attempting to test and you will need to create data that supports each of those conditions.

Similarly, you will want to assert the results of those conditions at various appropriate points in your unit test and/or code to demonstrate your coverage. That is how you will be able to provide coverage for the various branches of your code. In your situation, you will want to create a unit test that covers the situations where

- if(clist!=NULL && !clist.isEmpty()) is true
- if(clist!=NULL && !clist.isEmpty()) and if(folderId!=NULL && folderId !='') are both true
- if(clist!=NULL && !clist.isEmpty()) is true and if(folderId!=NULL && folderId !='') is false
- if(clist!=NULL && !clist.isEmpty()) and if(folderId!=NULL && folderId !='') and if(templateId!=NULL && templateId!='' && templateName!=NULL && templateName!='')
          are all true
- if(clist!=NULL && !clist.isEmpty()) and if(folderId!=NULL && folderId !='') are both true and if(templateId!=NULL && templateId!='' && templateName!=NULL && templateName!='')
          is false
- if(clist!=NULL && !clist.isEmpty()) and if(folderId!=NULL && folderId !='') and if(templateId!=NULL && templateId!='' && templateName!=NULL && templateName!='') and if(crec.ContactEmail!=NULL && crec.ContactEmail!='') are all true
- if(clist!=NULL && !clist.isEmpty()) is false

As you can see, that requires a number of different methods and test cases, plus data to support it. Again, your data for your Cases and your related contacts will need to have their fields populated in a manner that supports each of these use cases.

Comment: I got your answer. but can you give provide please specific answer to my question.its really helpfull..i really stucked like anything

Comment: One method will not cover all of your lines of code. You need to use separate methods to get the lines in each branch of your code, one of each `if` branch and another for each `else` branch. You'll also need to create Case and Contact data that supports each of those conditions.

Comment: I can agree but I need value in  mailList if its there automatically these method will get coverage: insertTasks,updateCaseLastTouchTime..im not able to achive this condition: if(clist!=NULL && !clist.isEmpty()) and if(folderId!=NULL && folderId !='') and if(templateId!=NULL && templateId!='' && templateName!=NULL && templateName!='') and if(crec.ContactEmail!=NULL && crec.ContactEmail!='') are all true

Comment: isEmpty covers Null. See the Apex Docs. It also covers isBlank (''), so your testing with additional qualifiers that aren't necessary. For some of these conditions, you'll need to create your test data separately with your method or use a Test Data Factory where you can switch these things on and off as needed. If its impossible for you to create these things without some of them, it may not be possible for a user to create them in an org without them either.

Comment: ya covered it. 100% coverage

Answer (score 2):

`ContactEmail` field is the email of the `Contact` which is associated to `Case`. And this field is not writeable.

> The Case.ContactEmail field displays the Email field on the
>   contact that is referenced by Case.ContactId. Label is Contact
>   Email. This field is available in API version 38.0 and later.

So before calling this below method in your test class

```
GSSCaseController.getEmailTemplateFolder1(validEmailTemplate.FolderId,validEmailTemplate.Name,caseList,validEmailTemplate.Id);
```

You have to verify on this below points to cover your mentioned `If` condition

- `Cases` should be associated with `Contacts` i.e when you are creating test `Case` data, your `Case` record should be associated to `Contact` test record i.e. `caseList` cases should be associated to contact's with email.
- And that `Contact` test record should have a value in `Email` field.
- There is no need to write values in `Case.ContactEmail` field (This field is not writeable), it will automatically pick the value from associated `Contact's` `Email` field.
- You should not pass the case list which is getting inserted, as it won't have any value in `ContactEmail` field, instead you will have to query all the case records back again with all necessary fields in addition to `ContactEmail` and pass this queried list to your method.

Comment: Updated the class & case associated with contact now.still no coverge

Comment: Hi @AnnappaPH, I can see that you are passing the same list which is getting inserted, that list will not contain any value in ContactEmail field, instead you have to query all those case records again with all the necessary fields including ContactEmail and then pass that queried list to your method. Updated the answer with this point. Hope this clarifies!

Comment: I have upvoted for you as well